# Opencart store page and links

Tags: opencart, href

I have locally installed opencart into the ".../shop" part of my website. Now I want to fit my site header and footer  to appear around the site.

Please can people help advise the best way of doing this. I have a header.php and footer.php included on ever page of my site but am not clear how to implement this on the shop page.

I am thinking that there is going to be conflicts especially linking to other pages via the shop section. Will the hrefs in my header in the shope section need to direct differently?

Comment: I have no idea what this has to do with opencart

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to goto your catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl and footer.tpl and make the changes.